# Strcmp() doesn't seem to work in my C program?

Tags: c, strcmp

I am writing a program to check whether a given word is a palindrome(a word spelled the same forwards and backwards.)

It's almost complete, but now I'm having an issue with strcmp(). Even if the forwards word and the reversed word are the same, it never returns a 0.

Here is the function that checks forwards versus backwards. If this isn't enough code, let me know.

```
bool isPalin(char msg[])
{
    int len = strlen(msg);
    char backwards[400]="";
    char letchar[2]="";
    int i;
    for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
        sprintf(letchar,"%c",msg[i]);
        strcat(backwards,letchar);
        strcpy(letchar,"");

    }

    if(strncmp(msg,backwards,(len/2))==0){return true;}
    else {return false;}
}
```

EDIT: Thank you all for your help, but apparently the problem was totally unexpected. I had a newline in one of my strings but not the other (still not sure why) but I was able to remove the newline and it worked for me. I also made the optimizations you guys recommended. I suck at optimizing :P

Comment: Can you print out `backwards` and `msg` to be sure they are being filled out correctly? Also you can simplify the final if statement to just `return strncmp(msg, ...) == 0;`

Comment: Works as expected here: https://ideone.com/FS00SO

Comment: Using `sprintf` to copy a character seems … unnecessarily complex?  You could use `letchar[0] = msg[i];` and then `strcat()`.  You don't really need the `strcpy()` either since the next `sprintf()` overwrites anyway.  There are other ways to do that copying; I'd probably use an index counting up from 0 as well as the one counting down from `len-1`. Just make sure you null terminate your string if you use that.  (And if you're only comparing half the length of the string, you really don't need to copy it all backwards.)

Comment: Can you show how you're calling `isPalin()` and how you check the result?

Comment: Your code seems OK to me. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Any time you're working with a widely-used library function and you believe you've found a bug, you're probably right - but the bug is almost certainly in your understanding of what's going on rather than in the library function. In 40+ years of software development I've found *two* verified bugs in vendor-supplied compilers and libraries - DEC Fortran compiler emitted bad code in a particularly pathological situation, and a C compiler's serial port access function screwed up the PIO setup - two instructions in as assembler function were reversed.

Answer (score -1):

Why bother with strcmp anyway?

```
int i = 0;
while(len > 1)
{
 if(msg[i] != msg[len-i-1]) return false;
 i++;
 len = len - 2;
}

return true;
```

If you suspect a function isn't working properly, eliminate the function.

Comment: Down voted because telling the OP to not use the function doesn't help him learn.

Comment: Reducing the executable code to spot the actual problem is one of the core techniques of debugging. "If you don't see the problem, reduce the code" is a much more helpful advice than "If you don't see the problem, ask on stackoverflow, someone else will see it". Showing the error in one particular case helps in one particular case. Showing how to reduce complex code helps in all future cases. The only thing there was to learn is that the code is so unnecessarily complex, that even the coder was unsure, without reason, if it's right.